# Intersection of Sylow subgroups is reduced to $\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Suppose $H$ is a finite group. Let $p,q$ be two primes and $S_q,S_p$ the associated Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$.

> If $p\ne q$, then $S_q\cap S_p=\{e\}$.

Suppose $p\ne q$. Let $|S_p|=p^r$ and $|S_q|=q^k$ for some $r,k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $S_q,S_p\leq H$, $S_q\cap S_p\leq H$. That shows that $e\in S_q\cap S_p$.

Let $x\in S_q\cap S_p$: then $x\in S_q$ and $x\in S_p$. This implies that $x^{p^r}=e=x^{q^k}$. Thus $x^{p^r}=x^{q^k}$. How can I use this latter fact together with $p\ne q$ to conclude that $x=e$?

**I am not allowed to use generalized euclid's lemma, GCD, LCM, "relatively prime", etc.**

Comment: Order of $x$ divides $p^r$ and $q^k$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's theorem, the order divides $p^i$ and $q^j$.  But $(p^i,q^j)=1$.